# I have a white and pink line on my LCD screen

Tags: canon, sensor

I was shooting a wedding video for a client and during the reception they had lasers where the DJ booth was for the dancing. As I was filming for around 25 minutes I realized that all of a sudden I got a pink and white line on my screen and in all of the videos. When I look back at the video on where it happened it seemed like the laser could of caused this. But I would never expect that to happen I was on the other side of the room.

There are 2 vertical lines. One is pink and the other is white. Let me know what you guys think. I also film on a Canon 1DX MARK II.

Comment: Videos of this happening, like [this one from 2010](https://youtu.be/qzyKLoEDb64) have been popping up on YouTube for over a decade.

Answer (score 2):

Yep... Lasers of sufficient intensity will damage your camera sensor. Being on the other side of the room doesn't help- laser light is a tight beam and, depending on the optics, can maintain that intensity over long distances. The International Laser Display Association has a [page on their website](https://www.ilda.com/camera-sensor-damage.htm) that discusses lasers vs cameras. Among other things, the page states

> Lasers emit concentrated beams of light, which can heat up sensitive surfaces (like the eye's retina) and cause damage. Camera sensors are, in general, more susceptible to damage than the human eye.

The description of damage caused also matches your description of your issue:

> Damage to one location may result in a horizontal or vertical line. In such a case, data from the entire row or column of sensors can no longer be read out properly.

I'm pretty sure that any damage is permanent, and the only way to fix your camera is to send it in for a sensor replacement.